# Adding elevation (shadow) to ExtendedFloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, floating-action-button, material-components-android

I'm trying to add elevation (shadow) to a `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton` and it just doesn't apply
I've tried so far adding:

```
app:elevation="8dp"
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

Even on different order as someone mentioned it may make a difference
Removed the `android:background` and some other attributes just to see if it collides with the elevation but no luck.
The complete definition currently looks like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/save_reminder_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_check_white_18dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```

Comment: The attribute is `app:elevation`. It works. Which version of material components are you using? and on which android version are you testing it?

Comment: Nice catch, I updated the `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06` to the latest version and it fixed the issue, feel free to repost as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute to set the elevation is **`app:elevation`** and the default value is `6dp`

Use:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        app:elevation="8dp"
```

[image]

Check your material components library and use the latest stable version (currently `1.2.0`).

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned, updating `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06` to `com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02` fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

and

```
 android:elevation="2dp"
```